# Cannot place order on my Desktop site

Tags: magento-1.9

I am facing very weird issue, when i add a products on my cart and then register as a new user and later on try to place an order by going to the billing information page. It doesn't move ahead. nothing happens after clicking the continue button. On mobile website everything is working fine. But on desktop i am facing such isse. Do anyone know any way out this ?

Comment: is it responsive website?  maybe the button that shown on mobile is acutally a different button from normal view.  Would need to see the site to investigate

Comment: While attempting to checkout on the desktop, have you reviewed the web inspector console for JavaScript errors? I'd start there.